# How do you incorporate TextSwitcher on top of a Button?

Tags: android

I wanted the text on my buttons to switch every time that I click it.  The only way I know how to switch text is Textswitcher, but I can't seem to find a way to use it with the buttons.  I'm sure this is a simple answer and appreciate any help!

XML file portion...

Button

```
android:id="@+id/Button_A" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
android:textSize="@dimen/help_text_size" 
android:minWidth="10px"
```

Java:

```java
Button alphaButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button_A);
alphaButton.setText(mGameSettings.getString(GAME_PREFERENCES_RIGHT, ""));
alphaButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        handleAnswerAndShowNextQuestion("a");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you should just be able to call `Button#setText()` in the `onClick` listener

Comment: Basically I'm trying to set up a multiple choice quiz.  And I want the buttons to be different multiple choice options for each question.  So I'm pulling it from a downloaded file.  However, even when I setText, the text won't change unless it's within the TextSwitcher.  Thus setText isn't working for my needs.

Comment: What does your code look like for changing the text? Also what version of android is this for? I don't have any problem setting the text of a button from within a click listener, whether or not it is in a `TextSwitcher`.

Comment: Does the text get set to the `GAME_PREFERENCES_RIGHT` string? or is it the code in `handleAnswerAndShowNextQuestion()` that doesn't work? I'm not seeing inherently wrong with the above code